# Unity - Startup errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, package, startup-error

I was using unity 2019.2 and from nothing, it started to have errors from the built-in packages (In brand new projects too!). I tried reinstalling all packages from which the errors came from and it didn't help. At this point, I gave up and uninstalled 2019.2, and I installed 2021.1.26f, but the errors didn't disappear (again in new projects!). I tried reinstalling all packages, but it didn't help. I looked over it on the internet, but I didn't find anything helpful. I have no idea how I should fix it. If you have a solution please share it with me.

[A bunch of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IEMz.png)

[another bunch of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdJee.png)

Comment: Looks like your "read/write" permissions have change to read only for the folders these things are stored in. Do you know enough about your operating system to enable "write" in just these folders?